# Cannot install Test::File on Perl 5.32.0 MacOS Sierra

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm attempting to install `DateTime` on my perlbrew 5.32.0, but the tests for its dependency `Test::File` are failing. The important part is as follows:

```
t/owner.t ..................... # File [blib] belongs to 703404669 (729761796), not 703404669 (703404669)!
t/owner.t ..................... 1/? 
#   Failed test 'owner_is with text username'
#   at t/owner.t line 99.

#   Failed test 'Intentional owner_isnt failure'
#   at t/owner.t line 146.
# STDOUT is:
# > ok 1 - blib doesn't belong to 703404669
# not:
# > not ok 1 - blib doesn't belong to 703404669
# as expected
# STDERR is:
# > 
# > 
# > 
# not:
# > # File [blib] belongs to 703404669 (729761796)!
# > #   Failed test 'blib doesn't belong to 703404669'
# > #   at t/owner.t line 145.
```

I got similar errors earlier, but  almost every package within my `~/.cpan` directory has a `blib` so I'm not sure which directory cpan is talking about.

My OS is MacOS Sierra 10.12.6 (16G2136)

How can I resolve these errors to install `DateTime`?

Comment: Do all the blib directories belong to the same user?

Comment: @choroba yes, it was implied by earlier error messages that all directories should belong to the same user

Comment: `blib` is the staging dir created by `make`. It contains all the files to install. `make test` runs tests against it. `make install` copies the files from `blib` into their final locations.

Comment: [File::Copy::Recursive does not have a `t/owner.t`](https://metacpan.org/source/DMUEY/File-Copy-Recursive-0.45/t). This appears to be [from Test::File](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/Test-File-1.447/t%2Fowner.t).

Comment: @Schwern that's my username

Comment: @con Do you have *two* users named 703404669? One with the ID 729761796 and one with the ID 703404669?

Comment: @Schwern I am 703404669, and I have no idea who or what 729761796 is

Comment: @con I think I see what's happening. What is your UID?

Comment: ah, `729761796` is my user id

Comment: How did you get an all-numeric user ID. I can't create those. Also, why? For now, force install (`cpan -f Test::File`) or skip tests (`cpan -T Test::File`).

Comment: @briandfoy the user id was assigned by my company - I didn't choose it

Comment: Still, why would they do that? It's bound to cause other problems in the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr: You've found a bug in a dependency. It's only used for testing. You can ignore the failed test, force install Test::File, then continue installing DateTime.

```
cpan -f -i Test::File
cpan DateTime
```

> ```
> # File [blib] belongs to 703404669 (729761796), not 703404669 (703404669)!
> ```

The problem is your user name is a number and Test::File does not seem to account for that.

`owner_is` checks if a file is owned by the given user. It accepts a user name or numeric user ID. If its given a number it [assumes it's a numeric ID](https://metacpan.org/source/BDFOY/Test-File-1.447/lib%2FTest%2FFile.pm#L1596). If 703404669 is your username it will get confused and use that as a user id. Your user id is really 729761796. 703404669 != 729761796.

Test::File can guard against this ambiguity by verifying with `getpwuid` and/or checking `getpwnam` first.

Congratulations, you've found a bug in Test::File. [Please report it](https://github.com/briandfoy/test-file/issues).